# passing pointers through multiple functions from main() C++

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, program-entry-point

this isn't quite working out.  Let's see if we can collectively expand our knowledge on this one.  Okay:

```
vector<vector<Point>> aVectorOfPoints
int main(){
    someConstructor(&aVectorOfPoints)
}

someConstructor(vector<vector<Point>>* aVectorOfPoints){
    functionOne(aVectorOfPOints);
}

functionOne(vector<vector<Point>>* aVectorOfPOints){
    aVectorOfPoints[i][j] = getPointFromClass();
}
//functionX(...){...}
```

I'm getting some error underneath the assignment in functionOne.  How can I better do this?  Thanks.

The specific error is "No operator '=' matches these operands".

Comment: How is `Point` defined?

Comment: @RSahu it's defined as a std point.  I'm actually getting that point from within the constructor and putting it within the vector itself.  Which will be used outside of the class.

Comment: Error? What kind of errors? Compiler errors?

Comment: @elimad No operator '=' matches these operands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is this wrong?

```
aVectorOfPoints[i][j] = getPointFromClass();
```

type of `aVectorOfPoints` is `vector<vector<Point>>*`.
type of `aVectorOfPoints[i]` is `vector<vector<Point>>`.
type of `aVectorOfPoints[i][j]` is `vector<Point>`.

A `Point` cannot be assigned to a `vector<Point>`. Hence the compiler error.

Perhaps you meant to use:

```
(*aVectorOfPoints)[i][j] = getPointFromClass();
```

You can simplify the code by passing references.

```
int main(){
    someConstructor(aVectorOfPoints)
}

someConstructor(vector<vector<Point>>& aVectorOfPoints){
    functionOne(aVectorOfPOints);
}

functionOne(vector<vector<Point>>& aVectorOfPOints){
    aVectorOfPoints[i][j] = getPointFromClass();
}
```

Comment: Thanks passing by reference works much better.  Is there any advantage to the pass pointer and derefernce route?

Comment: @hownowbrowncow no, it's worse. Use the references

Answer (score 1):

Use references instead of pointers:

```
someConstructor( vector<vector<Point>> &aVectorOfPoints) {
```

and the same for `functionOne`.

Your mistake is that `aVectorOfPoints[i]` indexes the pointer by `i`. If using pointers you'd need to dereference the pointer first before doing that, by writing `(*aVectorOfPoints)[i][j]`.